# Inserting data to a girdview without sending to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
dt.Columns.Add("Value1");
dt.Columns.Add("Value2");
dt.Columns.Add("Value3");
dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When i try inserting data to a gridview using this code the new values replace with the old values. how can i develop this to add new records without replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're rebinding your gridview. This will wipe the existing data. If you want to update your grid view I'd suggest adding the new row to a persistent data store and refreshing from that. This could be a database table or data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Every control in the page is recreated on each request. Take a look at the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

The typical way to handle this is to use the Page.IsPostBack property in your Page_Load method:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
    dt.Columns.Add("Value1");
    dt.Columns.Add("Value2");
    dt.Columns.Add("Value3");
    dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This will allow your grid view to persist between post backs.

Another problem is that you're binding your GridView to a new instance of DataTable, overwriting the current DataSource. To get around this, you'll need to persist your data table data in between requests, typically in a database, xml file, or some other data source.

Comment: It certainly looks like ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new DataRows to the DataTable already bound to the Grid. To prevent sending those to the DB as new Rows, call `.AcceptChanges` on the DataRow.